# ASP.NET: Passing custom list properties via JSON to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Here is a custom list (that I created for paging of my results):

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This list I want to pass via JSON to the View:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StoreProducts(StoreDetailsViewModel model)
{
    PagedList<Product> products = _productRepository.GetAll();
    return Json(products);
}
```

In the view I want to access to tho custom properties of my extended list but it's not working:

```
function getStoreProducts() {
    var form = $('#form');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            viewModel.products = result; // <-- success
            viewModel.hasNextPage = result.HasNextPage; // <-- fail, property is undefined
        }
    });
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: Parse the resulting ajax call JSON string. Try $.parseJson(result) which should return a javascript object that should expose your HasNextPage property.

Comment: have you confirmed that your action method is hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PagedList should be it's own class that has a property on it that is List, that's the easier route. Otherwise you'll need to write a custom converter for your PagedList class to not serialize as an array, but an object.

```
public class PagedList<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```